# I want to save the detected face as a jpg image in matalb

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-cvst

I have detected the face from an image. Now I want to store that detected face as a jpg image in matlab. Plzz some one guide me.

code for face detection is:

```
img = imread('C:\Users\Anmol\Desktop\face_recognition\Pgm\image1');

facedetector = vision.CascadeObjectDetector()
BBOX = step(facedetector,img)

B = insertObjectAnnotation(img,'rectangle',BBOX,'Face');

title('detected faces');

n = size(BBOX,1);

string = num2str(n);

str = strcat('no of face=',string);

disp(str);
```

I would be very thankful is some could provide me the code for storing the detected face as a jpg image

Comment: Have you tried `imwrite` ? http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imwrite.html?refresh=true

Comment: What happens if more than one face is detected? Do you want to save all of the images individually?

Answer (score 0):

You can crop the face using `imcrop`, and then save the cropped image using `imwrite`.

```
faceImage = imcrop(img, BBOX(1,:))
imwrite(img, 'face.jpg');
```